# Is It Possible To Add Custom Post Type Menu As Another Custom Post Type Sub Menu

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, admin-menu, sub-menu

I currently developing a wordpress plugin that is using two custom post types. What I want to know here: is it possible to add a custom post type menu as another custom post type's sub menu?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Yes. When you register your post type you need to set `show_in_menu` to the page you would like it displayed on.

### Adding a custom post type as a sub-menu of Posts

Here we set the "movies" post type to be included in the sub-menu under Posts.

```
register_post_type( 'movies',
    array(
            'labels' => array(
                    'name' => __( 'Movies' ),
                    'singular_name' => __( 'Movie' )
            ),
    'public' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => 'edit.php'
    )
);
```

If you have a taxonomy registered to the custom post type it will need to be added to the page as well.

In [`add_submenu_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page) the first argument is the page to assign it to and the last is the menu slug.

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_admin_menu'); 
function my_admin_menu() { 
    add_submenu_page('edit.php', 'Genre', 'Genre', 'manage_options', 'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=genre'); 
}
```

### Adding a custom post type as a sub-menu of another custom post type

To add the pages to another custom post type include the post type's query string parameter along with the page names.

To add the CPT Movies and its taxonomy Genre under the post type Entertainment adjust the code like this.

`edit.php` becomes `edit.php?post_type=entertainment`

`edit-tags.php` becomes `edit-tags.php?taxonomy=genre&post_type=entertainment`

```
register_post_type( 'movies',
    array(
            'labels' => array(
                    'name' => __( 'Movies' ),
                    'singular_name' => __( 'Movie' )
            ),
    'public' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => 'edit.php?post_type=entertainment'
    )
);

add_action('admin_menu', 'my_admin_menu'); 
function my_admin_menu() { 
    add_submenu_page('edit.php?post_type=entertainment', 'Genre', 'Genre', 'manage_options', 'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=genre&post_type=entertainment'); 
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. It works. But the sub menu cpt lost its submenu.

Comment: I've update my answer with a way to include taxonomies.

Comment: Hi thanks you! I had found the way to do it! But may be yours will give a better result!

Comment: the `show_in_menu` attribute, didn't worked for me.

Comment: Sorry for repeating. In order for the submenu and paretn menu to stay highlighted you need to give WP some more information. Ok, the 'show_in_menu' parameter makes the submenu to be current/highlighted when 'my_post_type' is on the screen. Now, we need also to add another action, that will highlight the parent menu. You could try this: add_filter( 'parent_file', 'menu_highlight' ));  function menu_highlight( $parent_file ){ global $plugin_page, $post_type; if ('my_post_type' == $post_type) { $plugin_page = 'edit.php?post_type=my_post_type'; // the submenu hook name }   return $parent_file; }

Comment: Thanks for supplying this code. I added my cpt pages through the menu admin with creating sub-menu to my cpt archive page, but I like this programmatical way better.

Answer (score 9):

Our custom post type:

```
$args['show_in_menu'] = false;
register_post_type('custom_plugin_post_type', $args);
```

Add him for existing Custom Post Type  ("product" for example):

```
$existing_CPT_menu = 'edit.php?post_type=product';
$link_our_new_CPT = 'edit.php?post_type=custom_plugin_post_type';
add_submenu_page($existign_CPT_menu, 'SubmenuTitle', 'SubmenuTitle', 'manage_options', $link_our_new_CPT);
```

Or add for our custom plugin menu:

```
// Create plugin menu
add_menu_page('MyPlugin', 'MyPlugin', 'manage_options', 'myPluginSlug', 'callback_render_plugin_menu');

// Create submenu with href to view custom_plugin_post_type
$link_our_new_CPT = 'edit.php?post_type=custom_plugin_post_type';
add_submenu_page('myPluginSlug', 'SubmenuTitle', 'SubmenuTitle', 'manage_options', $link_our_new_CPT);
```

Comment: Thanks! It's helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me

[image]

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'vrodos_plugin_menu');

function vrodos_plugin_menu(){
    add_menu_page( 'VRodos Plugin Page',
                   'VRodos',
                    'manage_options',
                    'vrodos-plugin',
                    'vrodos_plugin_main_page');
    
    
    add_submenu_page('vrodos-plugin',
                     'Games',
                     'Games',
                     'manage_options',
                     'edit.php?post_type=vrodos_game'
                     );
}
```

When I register the cpt 'vrodos_game' I set

```
    'show_ui'               => true,
    'show_in_menu'          => false,
```